# Jenkins balancing slaves

Tags: java, jenkins, load-balancing

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to balance between 2 slaves?
Both have java7 and java8 installed, there are projects what can run only on java7 and others can run only on java8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set "JDK" for each project and I set "Restrict where this project can be run -> Label Expression" to "jdk7slave || jdk8slave"

Answer (score 0):

Your should limit slaves to build this project at project settings.

Also your cat use [additional plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) to fine tuning of parallel builds

Comment: At the moment we have jdk7slave and jdk8slave, so projects run on related slave, but we are trying to find a way to make projects to run on both slaves

Comment: You can set multiple slaves to run on project. Just separate slave name by comma

Answer (score 0):

best practices in Jenkins!

Using node labels is important but redundant in this case.

The correct way is to let Jenkins decide which jdk to use in a job's session. 
Go to Manage Jenkins->Configure->JDK and configure jdk installations with the versions you need. then in the jobs you're running you can specify which JDK to run with using JDK field in the jobs configuration page.

You can further read here: 
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jenkins-the-definitive/9781449311155/ch04s05.html